# Quick evaluation of definite integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin 5x}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Find$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin 5x}{\sin x}dx$$

I can solve it by involving polynomials in sine and cosine as shown in the links below, but it’s huge (doing double angle formulas twice; I noticed that using polynomials in cosine is better because the integral spits out sines which are 0 between the limits) so I want a faster method, if it exists. Please don’t use contour integration:)

The only thing I noticed is that the integrand is symmetric about the midpoint in the given interval, i.e.$$\frac{\sin 5x}{\sin x}= \frac{\sin 5(\pi-x)}{\sin(\pi- x)}.$$
[Determine the indefinite integral $\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin 5x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854006/determine-the-indefinite-integral-int-frac-sin-x-sin-5xdx)

[Integral of $\int \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)} \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667307/integral-of-int-frac-sin3x-sin5x-dx)

[Expressing $\frac {\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)}$ in powers of $\cos(x)$ using complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320472/expressing-frac-sin5x-sinx-in-powers-of-cosx-using-complex-numb)

Comment: I think you need a dx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With $2\sin a \cos b = \sin (b+a)-\sin (b-a)$

$$2\sin x\ (\cos 2x + \cos 4x)
= \sin {5x}-\sin x $$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{5x}}{\sin x}dx 
=&\int_0^\pi(1+2\cos 2x + 2\cos4x)\ dx= \int_0^\pi dx=\pi
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fast and convenient method that doesn't rely on remembering any trig formulas and can be easily used to calculate similar integrals.

It involves complex numbers, but don't worry, I won't use any contour integration.

Using $\sin \alpha = [e^{i \alpha}-e^{-i\alpha}]/(2i)$, I rewrite your original integral as
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin 5x}{\sin x} \, dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} \, dx = 
\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{4ix}-e^{-6ix}}{1-e^{-2ix}} \, dx.
$$

Now I'll use the formula $(1-y)^{-1}=1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + ... $, also known as the sum of an infinite geometric series, to rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_0^\pi \left[e^{4ix}-e^{-6ix}\right](1+e^{-2ix}+e^{-4ix} + e^{-6ix} + ...)  \, dx.
$$

We've got an infinite sum inside the round brackets, but the thing is that when we open the brackets, we get integrals of the form
$\int_0^\pi e^{i k x}\, dx$, where $k$ is an even integer, and all such integrals are zero except for $k=0$. The $k=0$ term comes from multiplying $e^{4ix}$, present inside the square brackets, by $e^{-4ix}$, present inside the round brackets. The integral of this term is $\int_0^\pi dx = \pi$.

Hence the original integral is $\pi$.

---

UPDATE: Here's why $\int_0^\pi e^{i k x}\, dx=0$ for any non-zero even integer $k$:
$$
\int e^{ikx} \,d x = \frac{e^{ikx}}{ik} + const,
$$
$$
\int_0^\pi e^{ikx} \,d x = \left. \frac{e^{ikx}}{ik} \right|_{x=2 \pi}-\left. \frac{e^{ikx}}{ik} \right|_{x=0} = \frac{1}{ik} - \frac{1}{ik} = 0.
$$

A shorter method to prove the same thing is to use $e^{ikx}= \cos (ikx) + i \sin (ikx)$ and observe that $\int_0^\pi \cos (ikx) \, dx=0$ and $\int_0^\pi \sin (ikx) \,dx=0$ for any non-zero even integer $k$.

Comment: Why are those integrals zero :)))))

Comment: @insipidintegrator : I'll add an update to explain this :)

Comment: So you can integrate just like real numbers? Just note, then, that it should be ik+1 in the power and denominator.

Comment: @insipidintegrator : Yes, the complex exponent can be integrated just as you integrate real functions and is the most convenient tool of dealing with trig equations and integrals! If you know the complex exponent, you don't need to learn any trig formulas whatsoever!

Comment: @insipidintegrator : No, the integral of $\exp(i \alpha x)$ is $\exp(i \alpha x)/(i \alpha)$, just as the integral of $\exp(ax)$ is $\exp(ax)/a$

Comment: The thing is that the derivative of $\exp (a x )$ with respect to $x$ is $a \exp (ax)$. Now you can use $a = i \alpha$

Comment: Oh shit I got confused lol

Comment: Thanks @mitsuko

Comment: @insipidintegrator  You are welcome! And remember that the complex exponent is the most convenient tool to deal with all trig shit :) If you know the complex exponent, you don't need to memorize any trig formulas. You can instantly derive any of them from the complex exponent in a matter of seconds!

Comment: Now that's a good approach. Just yesterday, I used the geometric series to find $\sum_{k=1}^n\sin kx$ and now you have posted this answer. Just a perfect coincidence.

Answer (score 5):

We can generalized for positive integer k:

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin((2k-1)\,x)}{\sin(x)}
= 1 + 2\cos(2x) + 2\cos(4x) \;+\;...\;+\; 2\cos((2k-2)\,x)
$

Prove by induction:

Base case, $k=1$, is obviously true: $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{\sin x} = 1$

Assume formula is true for $n=k$, prove it is true for $n=k+1$

$\begin{align} \displaystyle 
\frac{\sin((2k-1)\,x)}{\sin(x)} + 2\cos((2k)\,x)
&=\frac{\sin((2k-1)\,x) + 2\cos((2k)\,x)×\sin(x)}{\sin(x)} \\
&=\frac{\sin((2k-1)\,x) + \sin((2k+1)\,x) - \sin((2k-1)\,x)}{\sin(x)} \\
&= \frac{\sin((2(k+1)-1)\,x)}{\sin(x)}
\end{align}$

QED

$\displaystyle ⇒ \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin((2k-1)\,x)}{\sin(x)}\;dx = \pi$

---

More direct way for proof, express as telescoping series.

$\sin((2k-1)\,x)$
$= \sin(x) + [\sin(3x)-\sin(x)] + [\sin(5x)-\sin(3x)] 
\;+\; ... \;+\; [\sin((2k-1)\,x)  - \sin((2k-3)\,x)]$
$= \sin(x) + 2\cos(2x)\sin(x) + 2\cos(4x)\sin(x)
\;+\; ... \;+\; 2\cos((2k-2)\,x)\sin(x)
$

Divide both side by $\sin(x)$, we have the required proof.

---

Proof using complex numbers, $z = e^{\,i\,x}$

$\begin{align} \displaystyle 
\frac{\sin((2k-1)\,x)}{\sin x} &= 
\frac{z^{2k-1}-1/z^{2k-1}}{z-1/z} \\
&= \left(\frac{z^{4k-2}-1}{z^2-1}\right)\bigg/z^{2k-2} \\
&= \frac{1+z^2+z^4 \;+\;...\;+\;z^{4k-4}}{z^{2k-2}}\\
&= 1+(z^2+1/z^2)+(z^4+1/z^4) \;+\;...\;+\;(z^{2k-2}+1/z^{2k-2}) \\
&= 1 + \;\;2\cos(2x)\;\, + \;\;2\cos(4x)\;\, \;+\;...\;+\;\;2\cos((2k-2)\,x)
\end{align}$

Comment: Another nice identity: sin(2k*x)/sin(x) = 2cos(x) + 2cos(3x) + ... + 2cos((2k-1)*x)

Comment: Pretty cool. +1

Comment: cos((2k-1)x)/cos(x) = 2cos((2k-2)x) − 2cos((2k-4)x) + 2cos((2k-6)x) − 2cos((2k-8)x) + ... + (-1)^(k-1)

Comment: Previous comment alternate sign can be shown with cos((2k+1)x)/cos(x) + cos((2k-1)x)/cos(x) = (2*cos(2kx)*cos(x))/cos(x) = 2*cos(2kx), all other terms cancelled out.

Answer (score 2):

Update: By using
$$ 2\sin(A)\cos(B)=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B) $$
twice, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)}dx&=&\int_0^\pi\frac{2\sin(5x)\cos(x)}{2\sin (x)\cos(x)}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\frac{2\sin(6x)+\sin(4x)}{\sin(2x)}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin (2x)}dx+2\int_0^\pi\cos(2x)dx\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\frac{2\sin(6x)\cos(2x)}{2\sin (2x)\cos(2x)}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(8x)+\sin(4x)}{\sin (4x)}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\pi(2\cos(4x)+1)dx\\
&=&\pi.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Even though your method ( and answer) may be correct, this isn’t what I asked for. I specifically mentioned that I used polynomials in sin and cos and needed a better method. -1

Comment: it would be ok.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Xpaul's answer is very similar to Quanto's, I don't think it is fair to downvote this where Quanto has 11 upvotes. Indeed, Quanto's answer (like all their answers) is delightfully brief, but all the omitted details are essentially the details Xpaul elaborates on.

Comment: @insipidintegrator see the update.

Comment: Oof. This is exponentially better than the previous one. Of course I reversed my vote. Thanks

Comment: @FShrike, thank you. I updated my previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the identity
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin 5 x}{\sin x}-1 &=\frac{\sin 5 x-\sin x}{\sin x} \\
&=\frac{2 \sin 2 x \cos 3 x}{\sin x} \\
&=4 \cos x \cos 3 x \\
&=2(\cos 4 x+\cos 2 x),
\end{aligned}
$$
we have $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin 5 x}{\sin x}-1\right) d x=2 \int_{0}^{\pi}(\cos 4 x+\cos 2 x) d x=0$$
and hence $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin 5 x}{\sin x} d x=\pi$$

In general, for any non-negative integer $n$,$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin (2 n+1) x}{\sin x}-\frac{\sin (2 n-1) x}{\sin x}=\frac{2 \sin x \cos 2 n x}{\sin x}=2 \cos 2 n x,
\end{aligned}
$$
we have
$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin (2 n+1) x}{\sin x}=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin (2 n-1) x}{\sin x} d x=\cdots= \int_{0}^{\pi} 1 d x=\pi}
$$

Comment: I am at crossroads so I won’t vote up or down. Reason for voting down: your answer is basically the same as @Quanto’s. Reason for voting up: @Quanto’s answer looks like some mathematician saw a dream and hastily wrote it down hastily; while yours seems more intuitive.

Comment: Do you like my generalization?

Comment: I’ll upvote purely because of the effort, _BUT_ user  @albertchan has already proved it. However, your argument is much easier to follow. I generally measure solutions to questions I ask on MSE by “could/should  I have been able to come up with this?”  If the answer is yes, then it’s a good answer.